# C# Entity Framework Database Migrations in Class Library

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I have a solution with an MVC 4 project and a class library.  Both the MVC 4 project and the class library have database migrations enabled on them.  I can run "Update-Database" for each project and apply both migrations to the database but when I try to add an addition migration to either project, the migration includes code to remove the tables from the other project's migrations.  Any help on this would be appreciated.

Note: This is not a duplicate.  This question is about migrations.  My problem is that each set of migrations takes over the entire database.

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066249/multiple-entity-framework-for-same-database

Comment: @Geoff, thanks for the link but not exactly what I'm looking for.  Basically, my problem is that each set of migrations takes over the entire database.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Code first right?

i'm not sure if this will answer your question but you can try either of the following

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists - this will only recreate the database if it does not exists
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways - this will always recreate the database, this will delete the current database including the data then recreate the database schema
- DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges - this will recreate the database if you change your model classes and will loose all the data.

hope that helps